memory_order_release and seq_cst synchronization
I remember that C++ concurrency in action book mentions that memory_order_release synchronizes with seq_cst so how can hardware / compiler reorder instructions of this?
This image reference is - https://youtu.be/M15UKpNlpeM?t=1640


release synchronizes with seq_cst only on the same atomic, no? That's why the example fails.

Yeah they are same atomic only, both thread have x & y both. You can take one atomic from them.

Firstly, note that all operations have to be seq_cst for sequential consistency to be given.
The example would be the same if both loads used acquire ordering.
In an acquire/release memory model, threads essentially see the modifications of other threads as a timeline, and they observe a point on that timeline, arbitrarily far into the past.

Thread 1 can see Thread 2 as not having modified y yet.
Thread 2 can see Thread 1 as not having modified x yet.

Because both threads can think that the other has not set their respective flag to true yet, they can both enter their if statement.
Formally, [intro.races] p14

The value of an atomic object M, as determined by evaluation B, is the value stored by some unspecified side effect A that modifies M, where B does not happen before A.

For example, x.store(true, release) synchronizes with x.load(acquire) only when the load takes its value from the store ([atomics.order] p2), but the value taken is from an unspecified side effect in the past.
If the stores use seq_cst (or nothing, since it's the default argument), you get sequential consistency.
In a sequentially consistent memory model
x.store(true) must happen before y.load() ([atomics.order] p4) (and vice versa)
in the total order ([atomics.order] p4) of sequentially consistent operations:
// A            // B           // ...
x.store(true)   x.store(true)
y.store(true)   y.load()   
x.load()        y.store(true)
y.load()        x.load()

No matter how you reorder these operations while respecting the aforementioned restriction, one of the stores always happens before a load.
In an acquire/release model, the following order would be possible too:
x.load(acquire)
y.load(acquire)
x.store(true, release)
y.store(true, release)


I don't think that answers the question. OP asks about mixing release with seq_cst.

@freakish is it clear after the edit now?

I think that the first paragraph alone answers the question. However it would be better to quote some standard. In particular it is not clear to me that that's how seq_cst actually behaves. It's a lot more than just losing total ordering guarantee. And the rest is just an unnecessary noise tbh.

@freakish OP is asking about why the reordering can happen despite release sychronizing with seq_cst, and to answer that, you need to understand a bit about the acquire/release memory model and how this synchronization doesn't prevent reordering in this case. You can't just call almost all of the parts of the answer that are necessary to understanding what ordering guarantees exist here "noise".

Of course I can. OP's question is about very specific thing. Which only the first paragraph addresses. While 6/7th of that answer (yes, I've counted paragraphs) is at best a digression. And not a brief one. Before the edit it didn't even seem to address the question at all.

Thank you for the answer. So you mean to say because they are just if and not while loop, loads can read any arbitrary past and not essentially the last release?

btw, in the video, presenter specially mean to say that hardware or compiler may decide to reorder operations and not that synchronization thing.

@Rupa it's the same for if statements and while loops; the load always works the same no matter where it is located. And the presenter is right in a way; the standard defines constraints on the memory model and it would be permissible to reorder the load before the store. However, the issue doesn't really stem from that; memory operations between CPU cores don't become visible to others instantly; they go through cache, and each CPU has their own L1 and L2 cache of memory. You can run into the same behavior on a debug build, where the compiler isn't meant to reorder anything.

You can think of operations being reordered at the CPU level as being the problem here, but this is ultimately the wrong intuition because it cannot explain a lot of atomics phenomena. Only a sequentially consistent memory model can be thought of the various thread operations being interleaved/reordered, for every other model it's more chaotic than that. It's really about the time it takes for operations to become visible and about cache.
